# What is a "stick-on dashboard bubble"?

Tags: terminology, phrase-meaning, literature

In Stephen King's *Salem's Lot*, I read

> ...Parkin's Ford with a stick-on dashboard bubble...

What is a *stick-on dashboard bubble*?

Googling didn't yield any meaningful results (anything you could glue to a dashboard of a car and looked like a bubble).

Comment: I was going to suggest you posted the whole sentence but [then I saw it](https://books.google.com/books?id=i-KRRR_5lbQC&pg=PA202).

Comment: [*Turns out the mystery bubble is a **sunlight sensor,** according to spokesmen from Chevrolet and Honda.*](https://www.cars.com/articles/2006/08/the_mystery_bub/) Perhaps Parkin used a cheap (non-functional) stick-on version to impress his passengers. Not dissimilar to people having fake burglar alarms / surveillance cameras prominently mounted on their house wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a really long sentence but the clue is in the part just before that parenthetical:

> ...riding in the Jerusalem's Lot police car (Parkin's Ford with a stick-on dashboard bubble)...

He's poking a little fun at the Jerusalem's Lot Police Department. The town is so small and underfunded that its police car is just the sheriff's personal car with a cheap light mounted on the dash. Around 1975, it would've looked something like this, only cheaper:

[image]

Comment: I think you are right.  I will add a picture.

Comment: These were know as *[bubblegum machines](https://books.google.com/books?id=M-heDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA275&ots=D3OZm5NFK9&dq=police%20%22bubblegum%20machine%22&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q=police%20%22bubblegum%20machine%22&f=false)* or *gumball machines* in slang.